# Rails create action renders as Javascript but doesn't show up on page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a menu of categories that can be updated using `:remote => true` in Rails without reloading the page.

My `new` action successfully renders as javascript and the changes show up on the page however my `create` action seems to render successfully but doesn't show up on the page. I can see the changes when I reload the page so I know the create action is working. It's just that the javascript doesn't seem to render the page properly. However, if I look at the response of the `POST` request in Firebug, I can see the intended changes.

Please help. I've spent hours on StackOverflow already trying to find a solution.

My Categories controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @category = Category.new()
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    if @category.save
      redirect_to(:controller => 'apps', :action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
    end

    @categories = Category.where(:parent_id => nil)
  end

  def update
    @category.update_attributes(category_params)
  end

  private

  def category_params
    params.require(:categories).permit(:name, :parent_id)
  end
end
```

My Apps Controller

```
class AppsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @category = nil

    @categories = Category.where(:parent_id => nil)

    @apps = App.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
      format.js
    end
  end

  def new
    @app = App.new()
  end

  def create
    @app = App.new(params[:id])

    if @app.save
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end

  private

    def apps_params
      params.require(:apps).permit(:name, :category, :image)
    end
end
```

The Create form (partial)

```
<%= simple_form_for :categories, remote: true,
                    :url => url_for(:action => 'create', :controller => 'categories'),
                    :method => 'post' do |f|   %>
    <%= f.input  :name                      %>
<% end %>
```

Create.js.erb

```
$('#categories-list').html("<%= j (render 'catList') %>");
$('#category-form').slideUp(350);
```

_catList.html.erb

```
<li class="pure-menu-heading">Categories</li>
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
    <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link"><span class="email-label-personal"></span><%= cat.name %></a></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I found some guys to help me on another forum.

All I had to do was remove 
`redirect_to(:controller => 'apps', :action => 'index')` 
in the categories controller